# ms access database and C#: can not open anymore tables

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have connected my access database to my C# project. I have 1760 rows in my database and when I try to print these rows to the datagridview in my C# project it gives me an error saying that the program cannot open anymore tables.also, it doesnt give this error all the time. Sometimes it runs normally with no errors at all. I have searched and asked for help to solve this but I got to a dead end I dont even understand why it is giving this error; I have debugged and went through the code a thousand time but couldnt see the problem.

I have put the code of my program and a screenshot of the error message.

```
edataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection();
        c.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Database.accdb";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * from omed", c))
        {
            c.Open();
            OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);  // this line was missing
                row.Cells[0].Value = Reader["ID"].ToString();
                row.Cells[1].Value = Reader["CELL"].ToString();
                row.Cells[2].Value = Reader["ncc"].ToString();
                row.Cells[3].Value = Reader["bcchno"].ToString();

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
                {
                    row.Cells[i * 3 + 4].Value = Reader["n_cell_" + i].ToString();
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd0 = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * from omed  WHERE CELL  LIKE '" + Reader["n_cell_" + i].ToString() + "'", c))
                    {
                        OleDbDataReader Reader0 = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
                        int counter = 0;
                        while (Reader0.Read())
                        {
                            row.Cells[i * 3 + 5].Value = Reader0["ncc"].ToString();
                            row.Cells[i * 3 + 6].Value = Reader0["bcchno"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
        c.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your reader in that loop, I assume the garbage collector sometimes keeps up with it, and sometimes it doesn't:

```
...
OleDbDataReader Reader0 = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
int counter = 0;
while (Reader0.Read())
{
    row.Cells[i * 3 + 5].Value = Reader0["ncc"].ToString();
    row.Cells[i * 3 + 6].Value = Reader0["bcchno"].ToString();
}
Reader0.Close();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As if using access as a 'database' is not enough, you are using (unnecessarily indeed) multiple readers on the same connection. 
Using multiple readers on the same connection is a serious problem by itself.

Second, you don't need that at all. You are selecting all the rows from 'omed' in your first call, you don't need to roundtrip to your database to do more selects from the same source that you already have result for.

Third, your inner reader loop, is effectively only using the last row retrieved by that unnecessary second call and thus a while(Reader0.Read()) is redundant.

A revised version of your code looks like this:

edataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
using(OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection())
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from omed", c))
{
  c.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + 
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Database.accdb";

  c.Open();
  OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  tbl.Load(reader);
  c.Close();
}

foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);  // this line was missing
    row.Cells[0].Value = r["ID"].ToString();
    row.Cells[1].Value = r["CELL"].ToString();
    row.Cells[2].Value = r["ncc"].ToString();
    row.Cells[3].Value = r["bcchno"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        var v = r["n_cell_" + i].ToString();
        row.Cells[i * 3 + 4].Value = v; 
        var resultRow = tbl.AsEnumerable().Last (t => t.Field<string>("CELL").Contains(v));
        row.Cells[i * 3 + 5].Value = resultRow["ncc"].ToString();
        row.Cells[i * 3 + 6].Value = resultRow["bcchno"].ToString();
    }
}
```